# Java version of c# Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, int sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, int destinationIndex, int length)

Tags: c#, java, arrays

I'm trying to convert some C# code to Java and I came across a line that calls this method:

```
Array.Copy(
    frames[row],
    0,
    concatenated,
    row*frames[row].Length,
    frames[row].Length);
```

The signature of the C# method looks like this:

```
Array.Copy(
    Array sourceArray,
    int sourceIndex,
    Array destinationArray,
    int destinationIndex,
    int length)
```

I'm trying to find way to do the same in Java with no luck. How can I mimic the same behavior in Java?

Comment: I should probably mention that the line preceding this one is a loop: for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)

Comment: You have trouble writing `for(i=sourceIndex; i<dest+len;i++)...` loop or trying to find some optimized code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try to `System.arraycopy()` ?

Example:

```
 char[] copyFrom = { 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'i', 'n', 'a', 't', 'e', 'd' };
 char[] copyTo = new char[10];

 System.arraycopy(copyFrom, 1, copyTo, 2, 8);
 System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
```

The output will be:

```
  ecaffein
```